# How can I change my password?

Tags: password

How can I change my password?

I have looked around [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) but haven't found anything promising. A few answers got me close, but the advice *always* came from a more advanced user. I am new to the world of Linux however I feel I'm following the directions 100%.

I love Ubuntu & I'm learning a lot of good information but I have been spending far to much energy & time on what should be easy.

Comment: It would be useful if you described your actual problem a little bit better. Have you forgotten the password and need to set a new one? Or do you know the password and want to change it?

Comment: Can you get to the desktop at all or are you stuck at the login screen?

Answer (score 10):

You can change your password with:

### command line

Open a terminal and enter

```
passwd
```

### graphical

The graphical method is preferred, especially if you have an encrypted home directory.

Open user accounts and change your user password from  there.

[image]

[image]

### Lost password

If you lost your password see [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password)

### Still having a problem

If you are still having a problem, please update your question with a better description.

Comment: +1 Comprehensive answer, given how vague the OP was.